# How to test 100 users per minute with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, web-testing

I have to test a website where the requisite is to have 100 users per minute for 1 hour so after 1 hour, 6000 users have visited the website. A first idea that crossed my mind was to set the number of threads= 6000 with a ramp up = 3600s but I noticed that after some time too many users were hitting the website which was more than the requisite of 100users/minute. I am confused now how JMeter manages the users(what is the average visit time per user). This is more tricky than it looked.

Anybody encoutered this before?
thanks

`Number of threads=6000 Ramp.up period=3600 Loop=1`

Answer (score 0):

Load Testing         - 100 User
Stress Testing        - 200 User
Endurance Testing - 100 User * 5 Loop
Spike Testing         - 500 User
Volume Testing      - 500 User * 2 Loop
Scalability Testting - 1000 User

Comment: sorry but it's not very clear what you mean

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).